# How to use inner join query in hql?

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

i have two tables
**table 1**
user(id*(pk)*,name,email,pwd)
**table 2**
tweet(tweet_id,message,user_id*(fk)*)

user_id is foreign key to user table id. I want to join these two tables using inner join in hql.

I am getting this error.

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: on near line 1, column 74 [select user_name, message from com.csc.project.user e inner join tweet p on p.user_id=e.id where e.user_name=:name]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
    at com.csc.project.tweetManager.viewtweet(tweetManager.java:80)
    at com.csc.project.tweetManager.main(tweetManager.java:103)

***this is my hibernate.cfg***

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>


<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/twitter</property>
<property name="connection.user">root</property>
<property name="connection.password">root</property>



<property name="show_sql">true </property>
<property name="dialet">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect </property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update </property>

<mapping resource="registration.hbm.xml" />
<mapping resource="tweet.hbm.xml"/>


</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

***reigistration.hbm***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.csc.project.user" table="t1">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the employee detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="increment"/>
      </id>



      <property name="user_name" column="user_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="user_email" column="user_email" type="string"/>
      <property name="password" column="password" type="string"/>
      <property name="created" type="timestamp" column="created"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

***tweet.hbm***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.csc.project.tweet" table="t2">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the employee detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="tweet_id" type="int" column="tweet_id">
         <generator class="increment"/>
      </id>


     <property name="user_id" column="user_id" type="int"/>
      <property name="message" column="message" type="string"/>
     <!--  <property name="user_email" column="user_email" type="string"/>
      <property name="password" column="password" type="string"/> -->
      <property name="created" type="timestamp" column="created"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: show your entities and code how your are running the program.

Comment: Please add the java code that you have tried when you got this exception.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your bean property as the name of DB field

If you want get tweets about one user, your HQL will be:

```
select e.user_name, p.message 
from tweet p, t.com.csc.project.user e
where p.user_id=e.id
and e.user_name=:name
```

Use always alias before fields and you can replace your explicit join with implicit join (with comma)